# Can you add color to labels created through Google App Script in gmail?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Is it possible to set the color of a label when creating it?

Can't find nothing in the documentation on how to chain setting of the color to this. Currently what I have is this:
`GmailApp.createLabel('My label');`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the functionality of GmailApp and many other service classes in GAS is quite limited. Please consider using Gmail API where you can set the background colour and the text colour of user labels.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels